# SwiftUI disable drag function

Tags: drag-and-drop, swiftui

I have a simple view which contains a group of Buttons which allow drag feature depends on condition.
How can i disable .onDrag based on the condition? The .disabled only disable click function.

```
    ScrollView
    {
        ForEach(animals, id: \.id)
        {
            animal in
            Button(action:{})
            {
               Text(animal.name)
            }
                .disabled(!animal.isEnable)
                .onDrag
                {
                    let provider = NSItemProvider(object: animal.name as NSString )
                    provider.suggestedName = animal.name
                    return provider
                }
          }
    }
```

Comment: What about wrapping the .onDrag closure in an if statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution with helper modifier. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
// @available(iOS 13.4, *) - needed for iOS
struct Draggable: ViewModifier {
    let condition: Bool
    let data: () -> NSItemProvider

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            content.onDrag(data)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

// @available(iOS 13.4, *) - needed for iOS
extension View {
    public func drag(if condition: Bool, data: @escaping () -> NSItemProvider) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Draggable(condition: condition, data: data))
    }
}
```

and updated your code would be

```
ForEach(animals, id: \.id)
{
    animal in
    Button(action:{})
    {
        Text(animal.name)
    }
    .disabled(!animal.isEnable)
    .drag(if: animal.isEnable) {     // << here !!
        let provider = NSItemProvider(object: animal.name as NSString )
        provider.suggestedName = animal.name
        return provider
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disabled usually won't work.

Create an extension for a View and put `if`

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition() {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
Button(//) {
//
}
.if(animal.isEnable, transform: { view in
    view
       .draggable()
       // or .onDrag...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.disable kills the interaction with the view therefore no dragging so it does what you need

you can check the documentation

> A view that controls whether users can interact with this view.
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/disabled(_:)

I think there might be a small mistake here, better to be sure isEnable param is correctly sent.

```
.disabled(!animal.isEnable)
```

Comment: `disabled(_:)` does not work on `onDrop`.

Comment: `disabled()` does indeed work if applied after the `onDrag()` and kills the interaction(just tested on iOS16.4 sim). Keep in mind that not only the dragging, but also other interaction will be killed, like buttons etc.

Comment: testing `disabled()` on macOS 12 and 13 showed no effect to `.onDrag()`.

Comment: My bad, I just noticed that I mixed `onDrag` with `onDrop`. Yes `disabled()` works for `onDrag`, but not `onDrop`.