# Is there a way to dynamically set onDrag on and off in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, drag

I have reorderable rows with an editable text views inside. To make rows reorderable I use the solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963988/20410653). What is important here, I add `.onDrag` modifier to the rows contents. The problem is, I want to **disable dragging rows while keyboard is on screen and user edits the text**. The solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389855/swiftui-disable-drag-function) here, like using `if` case, break the text editing: text loses its focus and keyboard does not appear.

```
if !isKeyboardVisible {
    rowContent
        .onDrag {
            // prepare drag
            return NSItemProvider()
        }
} else {
    rowContent
}
```

I would like to make something like this instead:

```
rowContent
    .onDrag {
        if !isKeyboardVisible {
            // prepare drag
            return NSItemProvider()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
}
```

But it is not possible. If there are any solutions, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Does `onMove` on a `ForEach` not work in your situation? Also, please show a [mcve]. Include just enough code that I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project to reproduce this issue.